# Read 1,000 private google docs with a service account

Tags: google-docs-api

I am trying to read 1,000 private Google docs (all in the same google drive folder) via the google docs api, but it only works if I share each file with the service account email address.

Is there a way to go through an authentication flow once which allows me to read all the docs in one go without a need to manually share each doc with the service account email address?

Thank you!

Comment: Why not share the entire folder to the service account itself? So that the service account will have access to all of the files inside the folder?